# Reddit Scraping Error HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Tags: r, web-scraping, reddit

I am trying to scrape Reddit using `RedditExtractoR`

My query

```
df = get_reddit(search_terms = "blockchain",page_threshold = 2)
```

Shows me the error as

> cannot open URL
> 'http://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/7vga1y/i_will_tell_you_exactly_what_is_going_on_here/.json?limit=500':
> HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'cannot open URL
> 'http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/blssl3/my_name_is_benjamin_zhang_and_im_a_transportation/.json?limit=500':
> HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'cannot open URL
> 'http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/blssl3/my_name_is_benjamin_zhang_and_im_a_transportation/.json?limit=500':
> HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'3 Forbidden'

How can I resolve it?

Comment: How many requests are you making to the server? It sounds like you may have gotten your IP address banned for too many server requests.

Comment: Where is get reddit from and what headers are you sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual cause for 403 forbidden is either:
a) issues with the server
b) getting blocked

I created an R program that uses the get_reddit extractor library to test whether you could get blocked by using it

```py
library(RedditExtractoR)

blockchain <- get_reddit(
    search_terms = "blockchain",
    page_threshold = 2,
)
```

And it worked like a charm no matter how I ran it.
Fortunately, the RedditExtractoR has built-in rate limits to prevent issues.
As per redditExtractorR package documentation:

```py
Question: All functions in this library appear to be a little slow, why is that?
Answer: The Reddit API allows users to make 60 requests per minute (1 request per second), which is why URL parsers used in this library intentionally limit requests to conform to the API requirements
```

But a 403 error due to getting blocked is still a real possibility.

If you start getting 403 either:

- wait a few days to make sure it's not the API that has issues
- use a scraping service or a VPN